# tabcolsep for a single cell

Tags: tables

I would like to use nested tables instead of `multirow`, I have this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\begin{document}

%\tabcolsep0pt %this makes the second table

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}           \hline 
 Test   &  Test2              \\ \hline
 Test 3 &  {\begin{tabular}{|l|} \hline 
            can i remove      \\ \hline
            the spaceing here \\ \hline    
            \end{tabular}}    \\ \hline    
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

That's how the output looks like. I know that `\tabcolsep0pt` can remove that space between the cell content and the table lines. But it removes it for all cells and it looks bad for the other cells:

[image]

Now my question can I set the `\tabcolsep0pt` just for that single cell containing the nested table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l@{}|}\hline 
 Test   &  Test2  \\\hline
 Test 3 & 
    \hfil\hspace{\dimexpr-1\tabcolsep}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
     can i remove       \\\hline
     the spaceing here  \\
    \end{tabular}       \\\hline    
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer to my question thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\multicolumn` to set the properties of the cell with the extra tabular. Then `@{}` removes the spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\begin{document}

%\tabcolsep0pt %this makes the second table

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}           \hline 
 Test   &  Test2              \\ \hline
 Test 3 &  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}|}{%
   \begin{tabular}{l}
     can i remove      \\ \hline
     the spaceing here
   \end{tabular}}    \\ \hline    
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l@{}|} \hhline{|--|}
 Test & Test2 \\ \hhline{|--|}
 Test 3 & \hskip -\tabcolsep{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
            can I remove \\ \cline{1-1}
            the spaceing here
            \end{tabular}}\\ \hhline{|--|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `multirow` instead of nested tabulars:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}   
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}           
\hline 
 Test                    &  Test2             \\ 
\hline
 \multirow{2}{*}{Test 3} &  can i remove      \\ 
\cline{2-2}
                         & the spaceing here  \\ 
\hline    
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```